# Definición del Context

Tags: android

Hace poco que llevo programando en Android, pero aún no tengo del todo claro el concepto del `Context`, me gustaría que me lo explicaran porque a veces se ha de pasar por parámetros y otras no y esto no lo entiendo, y además, en qué se diferencia con `this`.

Por ejemplo en códigos como este, ¿por qué?

```
TextView mTextView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Context` es una [clase abstracta](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/Context.html), y esta es implementada por otras de ahi a que el `contex` no sea siempre el mismo o no sea siempre valido, me refiero a que no siempre se le pueda pasar con un getContex() o similar pues igual se espera de otra implementacion diferente, dependera del componente de la aplicación, por ejemplo (la actividad , servicio , Aplicación ect) `Application`, `Activity/Service`, `BroadcastReceiver`, `ContentProvider`, ect  de la que se le esta pasando, se podria decir que es la entrada de acceso a casi la totalidad del sistema Android

Usted puede obtener el contexto invocando por ejemplo `getApplicationContext ()` como menciona , `getContext ()` , `getBaseContext ()` o **this** de aqui una de sus preguntas solo se pude usar **this** cuando esta en la actividad class Ativity o que de alguna forma este relacionada con esta, puediendo ser por herencia ect.

**Cuando se usa:**

Es usado para la carga de los recursos, obtener un `SS` (servicio del sistema), crear de una nueva actividad, obtener rutas de archivos internos, y para crear nuevas vista `view` que estas requieren de un contexto, en el uso de Servicios como LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE, y en otras partes que presisen de algun tipo de contexto `context`.

---

- **ContentProvider**: Realmente tampoco es un Contexto pero se da uno cuando se crea que se puede acceder a traves de getContext () . Si el ContentProvider se esta ejecutando en l mismo proceso de aplicacion, entonces esto va a devolver el mismo `singleton` de la aplicación, se mencionara en el punto `Application`. Si los dos están en procesos separados, este `context` sera uno de nueva creacion que representa el paquete el proveedor donde este se esta ejecutando o se ejecuta.
- **Activity/Service:** Este hereda de `ContextWrapper` implementando la misma api, conocida como base de su contexto. Cuando el framework crea una nueva instancia de actividad o servicio tambien se crea un nuevo contexto, se creara un contexto para cada nueva instancia de una actividad o servicio y a su vez su contexto de base para esta estos seran unicos por cada instancia.
- **Application:** Es una instancia unica `patron singleton instance` que se ejecuta en el proceso de su aplicacion se puede acceder a traves de metodos como getApplication() desde una actividad o servicio, `Activity` o `Service`, y usando `getApplicationContext ()` en cualquier otro objeto que herede de `contex` tenga en cuenta que siempre recibira la misma instancia desde dentro de su proceso.
- **BroadcastReceiver:** Realmente tampoco es un contexto mismamente el `framework` envia, pasa o le asigna un `context` en `onReceive()`,(PRestrictedContex). cada ves que un nuevo `broadcast event` llega se procesa el `broadcast` y se entrega, se envia una nueva instacia del contexto.

---

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/Context.html

Comment: They are geniuses, their contributions are invaluable. REALLY THANKS..

Answer (score 3):

Basado en la respuesta de SO [What is Context in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android)

`Context` representa el estado actual de la aplicación y permite obtener información acerca de su entorno de ejecución. Es una clase abstracta y su implementación depende del sistema Android.

Entre otras cosas, permite el acceso a recursos y clases específicos de la aplicación y también efectuar operaciones como lanzar actividades, generación de intents, etc.

Algunos de los usos más comunes son:

- **Crear nuevos objetos:**

  `TextView mTextView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
   ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), ...);`
- **Acceder a recursos comunes** como LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE o SharedPreferences

  `context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)`
- **Acceder implícitamente a componentes:**

  `getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, ...);`

Existen varias formas de acceder al `Context`

- `getApplicationContext()`
- `getContext()`
- `getBaseContext()`
- `this` si estás dentro de una `Activity`