# Activar Base de datos de localización con setGeolocationDatabasePath en Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment

Encontré que tenia que activar el acceso al GPS hay que hacer esto:

Dentro de:

```
public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {
```

Colocar:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationDatabasePath(context.getFilesDir().getPath() );
```

Pero andriod studio me dice:

Cannot resolve symbol 'context'

La verdad es que no se que es context... pero como lo resuelvo?

Comment: Todo esto tenía que ver con poder acceder el GPS desde un webview con java... y todavía no lo logro... asi que sigo en camino.
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar como contexto de la aplicaciòn:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationDatabasePath(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath() );
```

Pero si te encuentras dentro de un `Fragment`, lo puedes obtener de la siguiente forma:

```
getActivity().getApplicationContext()
```

por lo tanto tu còdigo serìa:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationDatabasePath(getActivity().getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath() );
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta y tu tiempo... ahora no me arroja error...

Answer (score 0):

Es importante entender el context en android, porque te ayudará en muchas ocasiones. Lo explicaré con un ejemplo.

Imaginemos que tienes una casa y quieres pintarlo. La casa tiene pequeños cuartos, cierto? Entonces, cada persona que vivirá en un cuarto tiene un color favorito que desea pintar su cuarto. Esa pintura solo se visualiza en ese cuarto, es decir desde otro cuarto no puedes ver el color de otro cuarto. Pero que pasa si visualizamos la casa como un todo, tenemos las columnas que son la estructura de toda la casa. Ahora hagamos la analogía con Android. Cada cuarto vendría a ser como un fragment y el context de cada fragment vendría hacer como su pintar. es decir **El límite en de cada cuarto**. Ahora si visualizamos la casa como un activity, todas las columnas, paredes que delimitan a la casa vendría a hacer su context. Entonces podemos entender al context como un entorno. El fragment tiene su context, el activity tiene su context. La aplicación tiene su context. Ahora para tu problema espécifico, el error que te indica es que estas llamando mal al context, entonces desentendiendo desde donde te encuentras lo puedes llamar de diferentes maneras.

Fragmet:

```
getActivity()
```

Aqui tenemos una sorpresa, porque el activity es un context :).

```
myWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationDatabasePath(getActivity().getFilesDir().getPath() );
```

Activity : Como el activity es un context, no hace falta llamarlo. Entonces:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationDatabasePath(getFilesDir().getPath() );
```

Espero te ayude, no te preocupes si no entiendes que es el context. Es una poco difícil al inicio pero con práctica logras entenderlo. Te dejo algunos enlaces para que puedas leer un poco mas al respecto :

- https://jarroba.com/context-de-android/
- [Definición del Context](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/4029/definici%C3%B3n-del-context)
- https://www.it-swarm.dev/es/android/que-es-context-en-android/969271935/

Espero te ayude :)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu tiempo y ocupación. Esta manera no me arroja error: getActivity().getFilesDir().getPath()